# multipart form data request RAML/ API kit router issues

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I'm trying to send multipart form data to an API. The API accepts a file(pdf/png etc) and uploads it to a slack channel. I have defined the spec for the API and implemented it too. Tests from postman work but when calling from a flow (using API as a connector) the API kit router seems to give me problems.

Here is the RAML snippet:

```
/upload-file:
  post:
    description: Upload file to a slack channel
    body: 
      multipart/form-data:
        properties: 
          files:
            description: The file to be uploaded
            type: file
            fileTypes: ['*/*']
          channels:
            type: string
          thread_ts:
            type: string
            required: false
```

In my test flow, I just have a file read operation followed by the transform operation and the api call. Here is the code:

```
<file:read doc:name="Read" doc:id="a32e1197-cb1e-4a8f-8681-126f01bc177e" path="ArrivalPass.png" config-ref="File_Config"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="82770a0c-7580-4324-95e8-a5424f180130" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
import dw::module::Multipart
output multipart/form-data
---
Multipart::form([
    //Multipart::file({name: "files", path: "ArrivalPass.png", mime: "image/png", fileName: "ArrivalPass.png"}),
    Multipart::field("files",payload, "image/png", "ArrivalPass.png"),
    Multipart::field("channels","C03PLA21UHX","text/plain")
])]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <slack-system-api:create-upload-file doc:name="Create upload file" doc:id="27fc431c-5c52-485c-8619-56b48ec096ba" config-ref="Slack_System_API_Config"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="97fd7b39-52bc-42a8-a41f-5569a9d13f11" />
    </flow>
```

The code fails with the following error:

```
""Cannot coerce Null (null) to Binary
Trace:
  at main (Unknown)" evaluating expression: "
%dw 2.0
output multipart/form-data
boundary='rc34b21aa'
---
parts : {

files : {
headers : {
"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
},
content : vars['create-upload-file-request-data']['root']['files']},
channels : {
headers : {
"Content-Type": "text/plain"
},
content : vars['create-upload-file-request-data']['root']['channels']},
thread_ts : {
headers : {
"Content-Type": "text/plain"
},
content : vars['create-upload-file-request-data']['root']['thread_ts']}}
"."
```

The API code doesnt even seem to run. Some kind of RAML validation seems to be failing my flow. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a value for `thread_ts`, even if it is an empty string.